# Map single array in database with ObjectMapper and Realm

Tags: arrays, json, realm, alamofire, objectmapper

So I have the following JSON:

```
{
 result: [
    " Sans Marque",
    "'t Boerinneke",
    "1 mètre de bière",
    "1ste prijs",
    "2Force",
    "2K Games ",
    "3M",
    "4711",
    "505 Games",
    "8x4",
    "ABB",
    "ACO",
    ...
  ]
}
```

Which I am trying to map with ObjectMapper in the following way:

```
class AutoCompleteResult: Mappable {
    var result:[AutoComplete]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        result <- map["result"]
    }

}

class AutoComplete: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var search: String?

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        //var categories: [Int]? = nil
        search <- map[""]
    }

}
```

It isn't populating anything in my Realm database. Since there are no keys, I can't use the search <- map["id"] way for example.
Does anyone know how I can put these results in my Realm database?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code? I think ObjectMapper cannot string array to array of RealmObject classes directly. So store string array to a temporary variable first, then enumerate the array to instantiate the model class from the string, then append it.

```
class AutoCompleteResult: Mappable {
    var result: [AutoComplete]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        var result: [String]?
        result <- map["result"]
        if let result = result {
            self.result = [AutoComplete]()

            for search in result {
                let autoComplete = AutoComplete()
                autoComplete.search = search
                self.result?.append(autoComplete)
            }
        }
    }

}

class AutoComplete: Object {
    dynamic var search: String?
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning an AutoComplete to a String? 

                autoComplete.search = search


See this.